# Induced cycle of odd length in a large graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to prove the following result in order to solve a different problem but I'm stuck; however I'm not sure if it is true, so I'll pose it as a question;

> Suppose we have a triangle-free Hamiltonian graph $G$ and we know that $G$ contains
>   a large *induced* cycle of even length. Moreover, suppose that $G$
>   contains a large number number of cycles that have consecutive lengths
>   (where the two "large"'s are both of the same order if you think it's relevant). Is it true that
>   $G$ must necessarily contains a large induced cycle of odd length?

Thank you in advance for any ideas!

Comment: TJIF -- I'm a little confused by how the large induced cycle of even length comes into play in a non-trivial way.  In particular, suppose $G$ was a triangle-free, Hamiltonian graph with a large number of cycles of consecutive lengths.  $G$ doesn't have the large induced even cycle, but couldn't you just glue a large induced even cycle $C$ to $G$ to create a $G'$ that does have one?  $C$ would only use one edge of $G$ (also in the Hamiltonian cycle), and otherwise $C$ and $G$ would not interact.  This certainly seems against the spirit of that condition, but seems to work.